# Help joining MySQL (tag) tables in Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, tags

Hello everyone I need some help retrieving tags that belong to a specific post.
I am working with Codeigniter and MySQL.

My tables look like this.

### post

id,
title,
description,
user_id

### tag

id,
tag

### post_tag

id,post_id,tag_id

The following is what I have in my controller:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('post');
$this->db->join('post_tag', 'post.id = post_tag.post_id');
$this->db->join('tag','post_tag.tag_id = tag.id');
$this->db->group_by('post.id');
```

When I open the page in my browser only 1 tag is returned.

Thank in advance, I tried searching for this before I asked but I didn't know what to search for. :-/

UPDATE: I commented $this->db->group_by('post.id'); and now my post duplicates depending on the number of tags. My post had 3 tags so i get 3 copies of my post but each has a different tag in the tag field. :-/

Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have one or more posts correctly associated with one or more tags?  At first glance the ActiveRecord syntax looks fine, however I might recommend creating a view in the database so MySQL can optimize it a bit for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you think I might have to alias my tables? When you asked if I had more posts correctly associated with one or more tags I inserted another entry with the same tags and noticed something peculiar when i used print_r(). Both my entries have the same ID, which is obviously not right.

Comment: @Mike S. I aliased my tables post_tag as pt tag as t and it solved the post id issue but I still only get 1 tag back. I checked my tables and everything looks good in there. As for your recommendation about creating a view in the Database, could you point me to some reading? I am very new to it all. :-/

Comment: Nick Pyett's answer appears correct.  As for creating a view, check the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)here. You would want something along the lines of `CREATE VIEW view_posts AS SELECT post.*, GROUP_CONCAT(post_tag) AS all_tags FROM post LEFT JOIN post_tag ON post.id = post_tag.post_id LEFT JOIN tag ON post_tag.tag_id = tag.id;`  Then your ActiveRecord query would simply be `$this->db->get('view_posts');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are grouping by the post id (which is correct), so you will only get one result with one tag joined.

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate the results into one column in each row.

Something like

```
$this->db->select('post.*, GROUP_CONCAT(post_tag) as all_tags');
```

This is untested, and will only handle the post tags, not the tags itself, but you should be able to get something going. I'd write the basic SQL first and then break it down into the CI functions. Also, I'd remove the second join to begin with to make it simpler.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I commented out $this->db->group_by('post.id'); and refreshed the page. My post had 3 tags so now 3 copies of the same post show up each with a different tag. Thanks this is a start, can you offer any further guidance or point me in the direction of some reading material on this subject? Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that grouping by post_id is wrong, only that it will  show only one result. What happens when you don't uncomment it? This tutorial should help explain what i meant http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2009/12/A-SWEET-Little-MySQL-Function-GroupConcat.cfm